# Java Android Studio game randomly ends when conditions are not met

Tags: java, android, android-studio, collision-detection, game-engine

I am trying to create a game in Android Studio that is similar to flappy bird. I'm following a YouTube tutorial as I am new to java and i believe I've followed it very closely.

My problem is that sometimes the game will terminate early, despite the gameOver conditions not being met. I have a function "updateAndDrawTubes" that draws the pipes to the canvas and also checks whether the player is touching the pipes. When the player does touch the pipe, the game finishes and goes to the gameOver screen, displaying the score. However, I am finding that even if there is no collision, sometimes the game will finish and go to the gameOver screen early.

My code is a mess, so apologies for that but any help would really be appreciated as I've exhausted all other options.

GameEngine.java

```
package com.example.mymainuniproj;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class GameEngine {
BackgroundImage backgroundImage;
Player player;
static int gameState;
ArrayList<Tube> tubes;
Random random;

int score;
int scoringTube;

Paint scorePaint;

public GameEngine() {

    backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage();
    player = new Player();
    //0-not started, 1-playing, 2-gameover
    gameState = 0;
    tubes = new ArrayList<>();
    random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < AppConstants.numberOfTubes; i++) {
        int tubeX = AppConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH + i * AppConstants.distanceBetweenTubes;
        int topTubeOffsetY = AppConstants.minTubeOffsetY + random.nextInt(AppConstants.maxTubeOffsetY - AppConstants.minTubeOffsetY + 1);
        Tube tube = new Tube(tubeX, topTubeOffsetY);
        tubes.add(tube);
    }
    score = 0;
    scoringTube = 0;

    scorePaint = new Paint();
    scorePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    scorePaint.setTextSize(100);
    scorePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
}

// this function is responsible for telling coins and enemies where to spawn
public void updateAndDrawTubes(Canvas canvas) {
    if (gameState == 1) {

        if ((tubes.get(scoringTube).getTubeX() < player.getPlayerX() + AppConstants.getBitmapBank().getPlayerWidth())
       //if current tubes X value is < player X value
                && (tubes.get(scoringTube).getTopTubeOffsetY() > player.getPlayerY())
                || (tubes.get(scoringTube).getBottomTubeY() < (player.getPlayerY() + AppConstants.getBitmapBank().getPlayerHeight()))) {
            //game over
            
            gameState = 2;

            Context context = AppConstants.gameActivityContext;
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, GameOver.class);
            intent.putExtra("score",score);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            ((Activity)context).finish();

        } else if (tubes.get(scoringTube).getTubeX() < player.getPlayerX() - AppConstants.getBitmapBank().getTubeWidth()) {
            score++;
            scoringTube++;
            if (scoringTube > AppConstants.numberOfTubes - 1) {
                scoringTube = 0;
            }
        }


        // repeats twice, once for the enemy, once for the coin at each X coord
        for (int i = 0; i < AppConstants.numberOfTubes; i++) {


            //if tube(x) in the array's X value is less than tube width (which is 90px)
            if (tubes.get(i).getTubeX() < -AppConstants.getBitmapBank().getTubeWidth()) {

                tubes.get(i).setTubeX(tubes.get(i).getTubeX() + AppConstants.numberOfTubes * AppConstants.distanceBetweenTubes);


                int topTubeOffsetY = AppConstants.minTubeOffsetY + random.nextInt(AppConstants.maxTubeOffsetY - AppConstants.minTubeOffsetY + 1);
                tubes.get(i).setTopTubeOffsetY(topTubeOffsetY);

            }

            tubes.get(i).setTubeX(tubes.get(i).getTubeX() - AppConstants.tubeVelocity);


            canvas.drawBitmap(AppConstants.getBitmapBank().getTubeTop(), tubes.get(i).getTubeX(), tubes.get(i).getTopTubeY(), null);

            canvas.drawBitmap(AppConstants.getBitmapBank().getTubeBottom(), tubes.get(i).getTubeX(), tubes.get(i).getBottomTubeY(), null);


        }
        canvas.drawText("Score: " + score, 0, 110, scorePaint);
    }
}


public void updateAndDrawBackgroundImage(Canvas canvas) {

    backgroundImage.setX(backgroundImage.getX() - backgroundImage.getVelocity());

    if (backgroundImage.getX() < -AppConstants.getBitmapBank().getBackgroundWidth()) {
        backgroundImage.setX(0);
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(AppConstants.getBitmapBank().getBackground(), backgroundImage.getX(), backgroundImage.getY(), null);
    if (backgroundImage.getX() < -(AppConstants.getBitmapBank().getBackgroundWidth() - AppConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH)) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(AppConstants.getBitmapBank().getBackground(), backgroundImage.getX() + AppConstants.getBitmapBank().getBackgroundWidth(), backgroundImage.getY(), null);
    }
}

public void updateAndDrawPlayer(Canvas canvas) {

    if (gameState == 1) {
        if (player.getPlayerY() < (AppConstants.SCREEN_HEIGHT - AppConstants.getBitmapBank().getPlayerHeight()) || player.getVelocity() < 0) {
            player.setVelocity(player.getVelocity() + AppConstants.gravity);
            player.setPlayerY(player.getPlayerY() + player.getVelocity());
        }
    }
    int currentFrame = player.getCurrentFrame();
    canvas.drawBitmap(AppConstants.getBitmapBank().getPlayer(currentFrame), player.getPlayerX(), player.getPlayerY(), null);
    currentFrame++;

    if (currentFrame > player.maxFrame) {
        currentFrame = 0;
    }

    player.setCurrentFrame(currentFrame);
}


}
```

GameOver.java

```
package com.example.mymainuniproj;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class GameOver extends AppCompatActivity  {

    TextView tvScore, tvPersonalBest;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_over);

        int score = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("score");
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);
        int scoreSP = pref.getInt("scoreSP",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        //update high score
        if(score > scoreSP){
            scoreSP = score;
            editor.putInt("scoreSP",scoreSP);
            editor.commit();
        }
        tvScore = findViewById(R.id.tvScore);
        //tvPersonalBest = findViewById(R.id.tvPersonalScore);
        tvScore.setText(""+score);
        //tvPersonalBest.setText(""+scoreSP);*/
    }

    public void showToastOnClick(View view){
        String text = "";
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonRestart: restart(); break;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void restart(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(GameOver.this , GameActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void exit(View view){
        finish();
    }

}
```

AppConstants.java

```
package com.example.mymainuniproj;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class AppConstants {

    static BitmapBank bitmapBank; //bitmap object ref
    static GameEngine gameEngine; //game engine object ref
    static int SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    static int gravity;
    static int VELOCITY_WHEN_JUMPED;

    static int gapBetweenTopAndBottomTubes;

    static int numberOfTubes;
    static int tubeVelocity;
    static int minTubeOffsetY;
    static int maxTubeOffsetY;
    static int distanceBetweenTubes;
    static Context gameActivityContext;

    public static void initialization(Context context){
        setScreenSize(context);
        bitmapBank = new BitmapBank(context.getResources() );

        setGameConstants();

        gameEngine = new GameEngine();
    }

    public static void setGameConstants(){
        AppConstants.gravity = 3;
        AppConstants.VELOCITY_WHEN_JUMPED = -40;
        gapBetweenTopAndBottomTubes = 800;
        AppConstants.numberOfTubes = 2;
        AppConstants.tubeVelocity = 12;
        AppConstants.minTubeOffsetY = (int)(AppConstants.gapBetweenTopAndBottomTubes / 2.0);
        AppConstants.maxTubeOffsetY = AppConstants.SCREEN_HEIGHT - AppConstants.minTubeOffsetY - AppConstants.gapBetweenTopAndBottomTubes;
        AppConstants.distanceBetweenTubes = AppConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH * 3 / 4;
    }

    //return bitmapBank instance
    public static BitmapBank getBitmapBank(){
        return bitmapBank;
    }

    //return gameEngine instance
    public static GameEngine getGameEngine(){
        return gameEngine;
    }

    // get screen height and widtch
    private static void setScreenSize(Context context) {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(metrics);
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        AppConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH = width;
        AppConstants.SCREEN_HEIGHT = height;
    }

}
```

This is my first time posting anywhere like this so please go easy on me if the format is bad or if I'm missing anything important!

If there is any other parts of the code that would help please just let me know and I'll try to be quick!

Thank you!

Comment: In your `GameEngine.java`, when `gameState == 1` in `updateAndDrawTubes()` method, put another parentheses after `&&` e.g. `if( (...) && ( (...) || (...) ) ) {`